# Read AudioUnit property (kAudioUnitProperty_SupportedChannelLayoutTags) return error: kAudioUnitErr_InvalidElement

Tags: swift, xcode, tvos, audiounit

I'm trying to read information from AudioUnit:

```
var value = AudioChannelLayoutTag()
var size = UInt32(MemoryLayout<AudioChannelLayoutTag>.size)
let status = AudioUnitGetProperty(audioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_SupportedChannelLayoutTags, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &value, &size)
```

it always brings me back a mistake:
kAudioUnitErr_InvalidElement (err code: -10877)

can you advise me please?

Answer (score 0):

The `kAudioUnitProperty_SupportedChannelLayoutTags` uses a scope of either `kAudioUnitScope_Input` or `kAudioUnitScope_Output`. That is where the error is from.

If the `kAudioUnitScope_Global` is changed to either `kAudioUnitScope_Input` or `kAudioUnitScope_Output`, you code will work as expected. But it will only return the first element of an array of tags that the audio unit supports.

When performing `AudioUnitGetProperty` on a `kAudioUnitProperty_SupportedChannelLayoutTags`, it puts the tags into the array with the size you specified. It also modifies the size you specified to the valid buffer's size.

Unfortunately, there is no way to know what the number of tags before trying to access it. So we can only access it progressively.

The following code returns the number of tags supported by the output of an audio unit. It tries to access 4 elements first, then expands that number by doubling until the returned element size is smaller than specified.

```
func supportedOutputChannelLayoutTags() -> [AudioChannelLayoutTag] {
        let elementSize = MemoryLayout<AudioChannelLayoutTag>.size
        var elementCount = 4
        while true {
            var layoutTags = [AudioChannelLayoutTag](repeating: kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Unknown, count: elementCount)
            let ioSize = UInt32(elementSize * layoutTags.count)
            var returnedIoSize = ioSize
            
            AudioUnitGetProperty(self, kAudioUnitProperty_SupportedChannelLayoutTags, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &layoutTags, &returnedIoSize)
            
            if returnedIoSize != ioSize {
                layoutTags.removeLast(Int(ioSize - returnedIoSize) / elementSize)
                return layoutTags
            }
            
            //Guard against cases where there is no tags.
            //The `AudioUnitGetProperty` will not modify &returnedIoSize if no tag is copied.
            if layoutTags.first == kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Unknown { return [] }
            
            elementCount *= 2
        }
    }
```